# Memory issues using ARDRegression in scikit-learn

Tags: python, statistics, scikit-learn

I've been trying to do some `ARDRegression` on a fairly substantial dataset in `sklearn` however it's using an almighty amount of memory and forcing me to have to kill Python. The code below should recreate the problem

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

X = np.random.random((50000, 100))
y = np.random.random(50000)

reg = linear_model.ARDRegression()
reg.fit(X, y)
```

And here is a screen shot of `top`

[image: top running whilst fitting model]

So my question is, is this expected behaviour of the `ARDRegression` function for a dataset this large or is there a memory leak that I should file a bug report about? I don't know much about the Automatic Relevance Determination prior and the literature seems pretty dense.

I'm using `scikit-learn` `0.18.dev0` and Python `2.7.10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to be answered [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/598).

Let me quote a developer:

> ARDRegression is not scalable as it allocates a matrix of size n_samples * n_samples. To solve your issue I would just switch to one the other sparsity inducing regression models I mentioned above.